# Modify Custom Option Percent Functionality to final price in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: custom-options, percentage, final-price

I am trying to modify the way `Magento 2.3.4` calculates percentage prices in product custom options to use the final price instead of base price so it returns this (`base price £30 + options £10 + option 30% = £52`)

I have updated updated :--

**/app/design/frontend/Designnbuy/Printshop/Magento_Catalog/model/product/type/price.php**

```
$finalPrice += $group->getOptionPrice($quoteItemOption->getValue(), $finalPrice);
```

and the percentage is added correctly to the cart but not updating on product page?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am trying to do the same thing.